# VBA - Save Word doc as pdf from Excel - Named argument not found

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

I'm trying to let an Excel script create a document file and save it as pdf file. Creating the document goes without a problem, but finding the right code to save it as pdf file seems to be a problem. I've searched the internet and there are many manuals and answers to the same question which all come down to the same code:

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Somehow that doesn't seem to do the trick for me, as it gives me the error "Named argument not found". Here's my script (I've left out the irrelevant lines and I'm sure the path and filename are stored correctly).

```
'Dim Word formfield values
Dim objWord As Object
Dim strDocName As String, strDocName1 As String, strDocName2 As String
Dim strMyPath As String

'Declare Word variables
Set objWord = CreateObject("word.application")
objWord.Visible = True

With objWord.activedocument
    'fill in a bunch of formfields

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strMyPath & "\" & strDocName2, _
    OpenAfterExport:=False
    .Close
End With
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that Excel doesn't know what any of the constant values of Word are, like `wdExportAllDocument` or `wdExportCreateNoBookmarks`.

In order to make that code work, you would have to add a **reference** in your project by clicking "Tools" ---> "References..." and then clicking the checkbox next to "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library".  You can then use a cleaned up version of the code that you posted at the top of your question.  Keep in mind globals like `ActiveDocument` don't exist in Excel and you will have to use `objWord.ActiveDocument` instead. Also, for your case I would suggest switching your code to use Early Binding (see [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm) for a description of the difference) so that you will have intellisense.  This can prevent troublesome errors caused by misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Blackhawk!

In the meantime I've found another solution. I needed another Object (objWordDoc) variable and I've replaced "With objWord.activedocument" with:

```
Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(strDocToOpen)

With objWordDoc
```

Nevertheless your suggestions will surely come in handy in the future!